# React native firebase version crash the app

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have below dependencies in app/gradle

```
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.+"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.+"
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    // implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    // implementation project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

With above config the firebase query is not working it is throwing an error with onsnapshot or event with get() both way.

When I change the firebase version as per updated instructions

```
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0"
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

app is getting crashed

Please help, as I have started learning it so unable to get it

Thanks

Comment: can you share you crash log?

Comment: I tried using adb logcat but its too lengthy to paste here, but at the end getting eof

Comment: without the logcat output nobody will be able to help you. The crash reason should be shown in red - this is the part you need to past here and not every single line of the logcat output

Comment: may be you have implementation issue
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup
follow all these steps
hope it'll help you